# Numpy, filter rows use mask of 1,0 values?

Tags: numpy

Opencv sometimes return a mask for filtering.

Give array `A=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`

and mask `mask=[1,0,1]`

How should I apply the mask to obtain `[[1,2],[5,6]]`?

I tried `A[mask==1]` but it says dimension not match.

`np.where` and `np.nonzero` seem not working too.

**Edit:**

Turns out `A[mask==1]` works,
It is in the real case I faced that `mask.shape` is `(n,1)` but not `(n,)`
that extra 1 caused the trouble.
`np.squeeze` solved the problem

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by “it is in the real case...” Also, does my answer work correctly?

Comment: The mask I actually got is like [[1,0,1]] but not [1,0,1], that caused the problem. Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear that `np.squeeze()` solved the issue! Of course, you can also use `.flatten()` or `np.ravel()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
mask = np.array[1,0,1])
>>> A[np.where(mask==1),:]
array([[[1, 2],
        [5, 6]]])
```

Answer (score 1):

Both

```py
mask = mask.nonzero()
res = A[mask]
```

and

```py
mask = mask.astype(bool)
res = A[mask]
```

should work!